# Is this custom version of the Blink spell balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, homebrew-review

I am currently on a campaign playing a Shadar-Kai bladesinger and I have already reskinned all my spells to appear like shadow magic.
It is really cool and feels great but until now I only reskinned existing spells without changing them at all mechanically.
I am thinking to propose my DM to allow me a shadow version of Blink to use and I want some feedback to see if what I propose is balanced.

> #### Shadow Blink
>
> *3rd level transmutation*
> **Casting Time:** 1 action
> **Range:** Self
> **Target:** Self
> **Components:** V, S
> **Duration:** 1 minute
> **Classes:** Sorcerer, Wizard (Shadar Kai specific)
>
> Roll a d20 at the end of each of your turns for the duration of the spell. On a roll of 11 or higher, you partially vanish from your current plane of existence and partially appear in the Shadow Plane (the spell fails, and the casting is wasted if you were already on that plane). You can dismiss this spell as an action.
> While partially on the Shadow Plane, you gain the following benefits until the start of your next turn:
>
> You gain resistance to all damage and immunity to critical hits.
> Any attack roll made against you has disadvantage.
> The first time you would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, you instead drop to 1 hit point, and the spell ends.
> If you are subjected to an effect that would kill you instantaneously without dealing damage, that effect is instead negated against you, and the spell ends.
> During that time, you appear ghostly and translucent.

It is basically sharing the same duration, components, the same 50-50 mechanics from the   original blink spell. BUT basically trades the "literally nothing can harm me, but I can't influence the material plane" trait AND the mobility/utility trait for resistance to damage, crits, disadvantage on attackers and some self-only *death ward*.

I made it race-specific and I think it is in line with the Shadar-kai flavor since it is like an enhanced version of the Blessing of the Raven Queen.

There is an updated version of the spell [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/202679/is-this-custom-version-of-the-blink-spell-balanced-v2/202688#202688).

Comment: Please forgive me when I steal this and pitch it to my DM. If you give me your character name I will call is "characters" shadow blink 

Comment: Feel free to use  "Durak's shadow blink" as you wish!

Comment: Welcome to the stack Giannis! For homebrew review questions the general advice is to not update the original post with modified versions of the content to evaluate. Doing so may (and most likely will) invalidate current answers. Instead, if you think you've made enough modifications and rebalancing to deserve a round 2 of "is my homebrew balanced?", you should probably make a new question instead. Do make sure that the issues mentioned here were solved beforehand, and that the homebrew was modified enough to deserve another question of its own first though. Happy stacking!

Comment: @Matthieu We also require 72 hours between iterations of homebrew reviews.

Comment: Ohh I get it now, sorry I am new. I ll see if I gather any more feedback and post the question again

Answer (score 10):

### Too powerful

The major draw for the original *blink* spell is that, for a squishy Wizard, the character is not around to get attacked. But the downside is that the character is not around to attack someone else or be useful. This spell doesn't have a downside. You're either normal, or unstoppable.

The character has removed their body just enough so that, about 50% of the time:

- (a) All attacks are at disadvantage
- (b) **ALL DAMAGE** is resisted (halved)
- (c) Damage you do take cannot be critical
- (d) If all of that somehow brings you down to 0 hp, you instantly pop back up to 1 hp
- (e) You cannot be killed instantly via spells/effects that don't use hp
- (f) It doesn't require concentration, so you could also have another damage mitigation spell running in parallel

And I don't know what to make of the spell having a duration of 1 minute, but "you gain the following benefits until the start of your next turn". Does it last 1 minute or 1 round? Since you also mention, "you instead drop to 1 hit point, and the spell ends" as one of the benefits, I'll assume it was a bad cut and paste go with this lasting a whole minute.

And after all that, 100% of the time, the character can attack normally, cast spells, move objects, take reactions, and otherwise be completely functional.

All of this for the cost of a 3rd-level spell slot (and I guess being the right race). Why wouldn't every Shadar Kai have this memorized/known?

#### Let's examine some of these things:

(a) - Looking at the beasts attached to shadows (*shadow*, *shadow mastiff*, *shadow spirit*, *shadow demon*, etc), none of them naturally impose disadvantage on attacks. Some can hide in shadows to give them advantage and an attacker disadvantage, but that still take effort on their part (usually a bonus action). Here the caster gets it for free. Additionally, many of them suffer when in direct sunlight. Not a problem with this spell.

(b) - With the exception of the "Blessing of the Raven Queen," I can't think of a single spell, feat, or feature that allows resistance to all damage. Generally, these kinds of effects will give resistance to a bunch of different damage types, or more commonly it's against non-magical attacks. But across the board, negation as an effect is less than 1%. And even for this one case, it's only for a single round, not 50% of the combat.

(c) - Once again, looking at other shadow beasts, all of them are still susceptible to critical attacks. There are objects, creatures, and what have you that cannot suffer a critical hit, but having it for the cost of a low-level spell makes this a bit too much. For perspective, at this level, a Monk can critically punch a ghost to death.

(d) and (e) mimic the effects of [death ward](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward), a 4th-level spell, just with a shorter duration but now for classes that could not normally cast *death ward*. But you would only cast this when you need it, as opposed to a backup in the morning that may or may not come into play.

(f) - As pointed out above, this doesn't take concentration. I realize that the original *blink* didn't either, but it also had drawbacks. But with this spell, the character is in the thick of it, expecting to be hit (albeit at disadvantage, non-critically, and automatically halved).

### My suggestions for the spell

(a) - You can either give the character advantage in dim light or darkness, or enemies disadvantage in dim light or darknesss. One or the other, not both, and not while standing in the middle of a brightly lit area.

(b) Only resist bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks. Remember, you're only partially on the Shadow Plane. The rest of you can still burn, freeze, be electrocuted, etc.

(c) Sorry, almost anything can be critically hit. Need to drop this.

(d) While it doesn't really fit with the theme of "shadow", I'm fine coming back from 0 hp one time. Ending the spell at this point is also pretty common.

(e) You have access to Counterspell, use it. You might be able to get away with saying, if the spell/effect has a saving through, the character gets advantage on the saving throw.

(f) With the above changes, I'm not as concerned about not being a concentration spell. Since it can end if the character is knocked down to 0 hp it's not a complete "set it and forget it" spell. Plus in your use case of a Bladesinger, they will have used their Bonus Action to activate Bladesong, and an Action to cast this, meaning they will have already lost one round of combat.

### Final spell would look something like

> #### Shadow Blink
>
> *3rd level transmutation*
> **Casting Time:** 1 action
> **Range:** Self
> **Target:** Self
> **Components:** V, S
> **Duration:** 1 minute
> **Classes:** Sorcerer, Wizard (Shadar Kai specific)
>
> Roll a d20 at the end of each of your turns for the duration of the spell. On a roll of 11 or higher, you partially vanish from your current plane of existence and partially appear in the Shadow Plane (the spell fails, and the casting is wasted if you were already on that plane). During that time, you appear ghostly and translucent. You can dismiss this spell as an action.
>
> For the duration of this spell, while on the Shadow Plane, the target gains the following benefits:
>
> - In areas of dim light or darkness, creatures have disadvantage on attack rolls against the target.
> - You have resistance against bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage from non-magical weapons.
> - The first time you would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, you instead drop to 1 hit point, and the spell ends.
> - If you are subjected to an effect that allows a saving throw and would kill you instantaneously without dealing damage, you gain advantage on that saving throw.

Comment: 1/2 Firstly, thank you for your time and effort. Your analysis is thorough, and your suggestions well thought. 
I have to disagree with the drawback you present on the original blink spell. If you succeed your roll, you are still functional on your turn, the only problem is you lose your reaction. Other than that, when you succeed, you are immune to everything. The real disadvantage is that you can't act knowing the outcome of your roll, but enemies can. This is still the case with my version of the spell.

Comment: 2/2 I still like your suggestions a lot. Though, about (b), the shadar-kai Blessing of the Raven Queen does give resistance to all damage... 
Maybe removing death ward benefits altogether and use shadow monster resistances and Condition Immunities are more fitting and balanced?

Comment: @GiannisPapoutsakis With normal blink you are not per-se inmune to everything, you are inmune to everything that are not in the ethereal plane or that can't affect the ethereal plane. You can still be attacked in the ethereal plane or affected by things that can affect the ethereal plane. Blink is not as risk free as it seems.

Comment: @GiannisPapoutsakis, in thinking about it, you might make the "drop to 0 hp" an always on condition. So most of the powers only manifest when the character is half-in/half-out. But for the whole duration, if they get knocked to 0, they get back up and the spell stops. Something to consider for the next iteration.

Answer (score -3):

### This seems way too strong (or possibly too weak). Reskin *Blur* instead.

This spell heavily covers what *Blur* does, so I'll use that as main comparison.

The first problem that I can see is that this should almost definitely be a Concentration spell, lasting effects like this usually are.

The second is that this is *Blur*+ that works 50% of the time, random chance on defensive abilities will always happen when they're useless and never happen while useful.

Third, effects that instant kill are rare and expensive. This currently counters the lvl9 spell *Power word kill*.

Comment: I'm unclear on why you're comparing this to Blur when the OP stated they're comparing it to Blink. This is relevant because Blur as a 2nd level spell does require concentration, but Blink on 3rd level does not, which seems to negate your point. I'm unclear what you're trying to state with your 2nd point. As for your 3rd point, can you expound on why it's unbalanced that a 3rd level spell counters PWK? There's a lot of counters to PWK, one could argue that the extra hit points provided by the 2nd level Aid spell counters PWK.

Comment: Well, the spell is practically the same as blink not blur.The 50% of the time is the same. 
I dont feel like making it concentration because the original spell is not a concentration spell and has the same duration etc. 

I don't think you understand how good blink is. Practically, for this 50% of the time, NOTHING can harm you. It also negates power word kill and does not end the spell!!  I really wanted a toned down version to be able to tank a bit. Also, original blink does give you some incredible mobility benefits bypassing any 10ft obstacle, getting you out of harms way without AoO.

Comment: While you are correct that an absolute defense is strictly better than a probabilistic defense, I would remind you that both AC and Saves are also probabilistic in nature. Probabilistic defenses are problematic against one-off effects (such as Power Word Kill) however a character is typically attacked by a variety of small/mid scale attacks and negating a percentage of them is beneficial too. The one issue with _Blink_, and this version, is more about the _when_: the character cannot plan their turn based on whether they'll blink out, and a foe can plan their attacks based on it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. true, however the large majority of defensive spells are either absolute (heals/bonus hp/something similar) or *weighting* the already existing average

Comment: The reason I compare this to *Blur* rather than the *Blink* that the author did is because *Blink* is a mage "I dont want to be attacked" spell, *Blur* is a "I'm in melee and want to protect my backline" spell. And the author stated intent for this to be the latter

Comment: @GiannisPapoutsakis *Blink* does not counter *Power Word: Kill*, it makes it be redirected to another party member. This spell **stops** the effect. This is the same for all the qualms I have with this spell, though admittedly I should have worded it better and not massively sleep deprived.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I am already working on an other version of the spell using your feedback (mostly @MivaScott, thank you for that). I left the death ward elements out and focused on a more shadow monster based set of boons. I ll post it on an other question tomorrow.

Comment: @Cassie, there is an updated version (2 actually) (link in the main question) and I would love to see your thoughts on these.

Comment: @GiannisPapoutsakis MivaScott's answer covers my opinion of it so I hadn't put an answer

Comment: Nice! Thanks. It seems that the V2 of the second post captures the flavor I wanted in a balanced spell for 3rd lvl.