# Is this custom version of the Blink spell balanced? V2

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, homebrew-review

This is an iteration on my [previous attempt to create the Shadow Blink spell.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/202607/is-this-custom-version-of-the-blink-spell-balanced/202616?noredirect=1#comment553941_202616) after I have taken into consideration feedback and suggestions.
I am currently on a campaign playing a Shadar-Kai bladesinger.I reskinned all my raw spells to appear like shadow magic, but I also want to create a spell similar to blink to fit the theme.
I ended up with two versions of the spell (with bold the diferences between the two):

> #### Shadow Blink v1
>
> *3rd level transmutation*
> **Casting Time:** 1 action
> **Range:** Self
> **Target:** Self
> **Components:** V, S
> **Duration:** 1 minute
> **Classes:** Sorcerer, Wizard (Shadar Kai specific)
>
> Roll a d20 at the end of each of your turns for the duration of the spell. On a roll of 11 or higher, you partially vanish from your current plane of existence and partially appear in the Shadow Plane (the spell fails, and the casting is wasted if you were already on that plane). During that time, **you assume some traits of a [shadow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17010-shadow) and** appear ghostly and translucent. You can dismiss this spell as an action.
>
> For the duration of this spell, while partially on the Shadow Plane, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - In areas of dim light or darkness, creatures have disadvantage on
>   attack rolls against you
> - You have resistance against Acid, Cold, Fire, Lightning, Thunder,
>   Poison; Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks
> - **You are immune to Exhaustion, Frightened, Grappled, Paralyzed, Petrified, Poisoned, Restrained**

> #### Shadow Blink v2
>
> *3rd level transmutation*
> **Casting Time:** 1 action
> **Range:** Self
> **Target:** Self
> **Components:** V, S
> **Duration:** 1 minute
> **Classes:** Sorcerer, Wizard (Shadar Kai specific)
>
> Roll a d20 at the end of each of your turns for the duration of the spell. On a roll of 11 or higher, you partially vanish from your current plane of existence and partially appear in the Shadow Plane (the spell fails, and the casting is wasted if you were already on that plane). During that time, you appear ghostly and translucent. You can dismiss this spell as an action.
>
> For the duration of this spell, while partially on the Shadow Plane, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - In areas of dim light or darkness, creatures have disadvantage on
>   attack rolls against you
> - You have resistance against Acid, Cold, Fire, Lightning, Thunder,
>   Poison; Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks
> - **If you are subjected to an effect that allows a saving throw and would kill you instantaneously without dealing damage, you gain advantage on that saving throw.**
>
> **Also, for the duration of the spell(regardless of the roll), the first time you would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, you instead drop to 1 hit point, and the spell ends.**

Is any version (or both) balanced for a 3rd level spell slot? Do you have any other suggestions to further balance this spell and to enhance the flavour, uniqueness, and usability?

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1 is still overpowered and difficult to make work

Handing out immunities is a big deal. Just like I [mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202616/38834) in your first attempt, the whole "resist all damage" thing it more of a boon, than a spell anyone can cast. Especially at low levels. You expanded the list of things that the caster is resistant to, which is okay. Still not an everything and more in line with being a shade.

But how would immunities work? Since they only effect the player while in the Shadow Plane, what happened if they already had one of the conditions? They're exhausted for their turn, but not exhausted while in the Shadow Plane, but exhausted again at the start of their next turn? What about petrified? They un-turn-to-stone for a period of time? Too much bookkeeping and probably a bunch of loopholes.

Remember, the character is still partially on their current plane. That makes them attackable, hitable, burnable, grappleable, an so on. The original *blink* spell let you move around because you completely left the plane; not so with this spell.

## Option 2 is better (In my not humble opinion)

Considering this is almost exactly what I recommend in the previous thread, I think this is a workable spell. As I stated above, adding "Acid, Cold, Fire, Lightning, Thunder, Poison" to the resistances isn't earth shattering nor game breaking since it's only really working about 50% of the combat.

Comment: Thanks again, your contribution really helped me. I tend to think that option 2 is more viable and more balanced... I included option 1 because I liked it flavor wise, but it will be indeed a pain to book keep

Answer (score -2):

2 Things:

1. Amazing Ideas, consider changing "the target" as the range is self the target
   can
   only be the caster so it seems off... not that big a problem thou.
2. V2 seems relatively balanced but V1 has lots of questions unanswered with the
   parts highlighted in bold, what defines "**some traits of a shadow**"? Are they
   randomly choosen, just specific ones(if yes define), or otherwise.
   Also the Immunities seem quite over powered and will be hard to balance as the DM,
   Conditions are often difficult barriers to overcome and Immunities to them
   valuable. Consider changing it to resistance/rolling with advantage when rolling
   against them. Exhaustion, Frightened and Poisoned might also need further
   clarification, like what happens if I already am affected by these three.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).